# Visual Studio 2003 IDE crashes on Windows 7 while deploying Smart Device Application

Tags: windows-7, compact-framework, visual-studio-2003

I am working on a Windows 7 32 bit development PC. I have to support a Compact Framework 1 smart device application running on Windows CE devices. Visual Studio .NET 2003 builds the application fine, but when it comes to deploying it on a device for debugging, it crashes with a Windows 7 "Stopped working, looking for a solution" prompt. Windows cannot find any.

This crash may be related to Windows Mobile Device Center connection since it doesn't matter if the connection is established via USB or DMA to a Device Emulator.

I have tried Windows 7 compatibility tab for devenv.exe. Windows XP or Vista options did not work.

Windows 7 XP Mode is out of question since I need to connect to a USB device. XP Mode is very unsuccessful on connected devices.

My only option now seems to be working on a Windows XP machine. Any solutions for my Windows 7 PC will be most welcome.

Comment: Is studio 2005 an option?  It can do CF 1.0

Comment: That's interesting! I didn't know it was possible to do CF 1.0 with VS 2005.